# Regular Expression to match /u/{word or underscore or numbers}

Tags: c#, regex

I have tried and failed for two days now to successfully match /u/{word or underscore or numbers}. I also need to ignore the value if it is in a link (ex: `<a href="asdfasdf/u/word" />`. I have exhausted all options. Can someone please help me out here?

Edit: I am unfamiliar with regular expressions and am still trying to figure them out. Excuse me if this is a noobish question. And to clarify, I can get the matches fine. I just don't understand in Regex how to ignore a match completely if a certain character follows.

Example:

> `/u/username`
>
> `/u/username` this is
>
> this/is/u/user 
>    `<a href="http://www.regex.com/u/something/" />`

I want to match the first two occurrences of /u/username.

This is embarrassing, but here is my current regex `/u/\w*[^"]`

Comment: Adding some test case and examples can help

Comment: Sorry, not used to posting... Just added a quick example that should show what I am trying to do.

Comment: you need to read about Negative Lookahead. could you put the regex you have till now ?

Comment: I added that to the post, it is probably terrible.

Comment: You want to match `/u/username` but not `/u/user`? What is the distinguishing characteristic here? Why match the first two cases and not the third?

Comment: I don't know where you got /u/username but not /u/user. See my example, I just want the first two occurrences to match even if there is a space in front of it, but only if there is a space or nothing in front of it. If there is a quote in front of it, or a forward slash in front of it, I don't want it to match either.

Comment: in the third example you mean `this/is/u/user <a href="http://www.regex.com/u/username/" />`

Comment: The whole quoted text is my example. I don't want this/is/u/user to contain a match, or the link to contain a match. But I want the first two occurrences of /u/username to match. This is just a little hard to explain, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use do this pattern:

```
/u/\w*
```

It will match the string `/u/` followed by zero or more letters, numbers, or underscores. To ensure that the string consists only of this pattern, use start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors, like this:

```
^/u/\w*$
```

For example:

```
string result = Regex.Match(input, @"^/u/\w*$").Value;
```

---

If you're trying to do some special parsing of HTML, I'm afraid regular expressions are a pretty bad option. You really should find some way of properly parsing the document first. Nevertheless, here's a *very* crude pattern that will ignore this sequence if it happens to be within inside an `href` attribute (it also assumes the attribute value will be surrounded by quotation marks):

```
(?<!href="[^"]*)/u/\w*
```

For example:

```
string input = @"<a href=""http://x/u/foo"">/u/bar</a>";
string pattern = @"(?<!href=""[^""]+)/u/\w*";
string Regex.Match(input, pattern).Value; // will match /u/bar but not /u/foo
```

---

This pattern will match any sequence that doesn't have a word character (letter, number, or underscore), quote, or forward slash in front of it:

```
(?<![\w""/])/u/\w*
```

This example shows how it can be used get all matches from the string:

```
var input = @"/u/username
/u/username this is
this/is/u/user <a href=""http://www.regex.com/u/something/"" />";
var pattern = @"(?<![\w""/])/u/\w*";
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

The output will me:

```
/u/username
/u/username
```

Comment: This matches it in any way possible. It also matches it in this string <a href="something.com/u/testing"></a> which I am trying to ignore.

Comment: What if there is a space after it or before it? I try to understand this stuff, I have gotten up to the URL part but I got lost.

Comment: Can you check out my updated question? I updated the example. I don't want to parse html, I want to ignore it. If there is a quote after it, don't match. If there is a / after it, don't match it. How can I do that? It also needs to be multiline as well and if you try the exact copy/paste of what I posted, it doesn't work correctly. I'm sorry to give you problems with this.

Comment: @CalebKeith It's no problem, but when it comes to regular expressions, you have to be ***very precise*** when telling people what you want to match.

Comment: Awesome, this is perfect. That is amazing. I am still trying to understand that, but that will be really helpful in future circumstances too. I had to replace the * with + since I needed some text after the /u/... I didn't specify that though. Thanks so much for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will meet your test scenario

```
\w*(/u)*[a-z,A-Z,0-9]+$
```

This actually catches on the characters unique to HTML tags, so as long as you want to ignore HTML code.  this will do the trick.